# how can I get the response from JSON format using script?

Tags: json, groovy, automation, soapui

I'm using SoapUI Pro 4.5.0 and also a beginner for this tool. I need to get the value from the response (JSON format). Can anyone give me sample code for this?

Note: I'm using the REST based service not SOAP based service.

Comment: <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoapUI includes JsonSlurper class in the groovy jar, so you just have to import it like

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
```

and then the response is obtained as

```
responseContent = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("<test_step_name>").getPropertyValue("Response")

jsonresponse = new JsonSlurper().parseTest(responseContent)
```

Now you can access the elements in response like

```
jsonresponse.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) from a Groovy script.  You may need to add the JSONPath Jar to the /bin/ext directory.

I don't have SoapUI in front of me, but in the groovy script it would be something like:

```
def getResponse = context.expand( '${SomeGet#response}' )
def jsonSuff = JsonPath.read(getResponse, "\$..*")
```

Here is what was in my POM if you have trouble with the other JAR (I had created an external JAR that I used in SoapUI).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And this was my import statement:
    import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath

Comment: could you please tell me from where can I get the JSONPath.jar file?

Comment: I have downloaded the following jar files from here. http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/0.5.3